# Do destructors affect performance?

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management, garbage-collection, destructor

I have added a destructor to one of my base classes which I use to help hunt for memory leaks like so:

```
#if DEBUG
~BaseViewModel()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("View Model Disposed");
}
#endif
```

Even removing the `Debug.WriteLine` code

Will having the destructor present affect performance for a debug build?

Comment: Having one will keep your object alive longer because it will be added to the GC's finalizer queue. Don't add one if it is not needed.

Comment: You don't need it... anything you remove, will improve performance some way or another, but that's something you could test for. If not using unmanaged resources, typically you don't need it.

Comment: Firstly, for performance checks - you need to test this yourself, that's the only way. Secondly, this looks like a terrible way to find memory leaks.

Comment: Learn to use profilers so you dont have to test like this

Comment: You also need to get your terminology straight. Destructor and Disposal and *not* the same concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors)

> Empty finalizers should not be used. When a class contains a
>   finalizer, an entry is created in the Finalize queue. When the
>   finalizer is called, the garbage collector is invoked to process the
>   queue. An empty finalizer just causes a needless loss of performance.

You need a destructor(finalizer) only if you have unmanaged resources in your class. And if you add a destructor you should suppress Finalization in the Dispose. Otherwise it will cause your objects resides in memory for longer, because they will be added to the finalizer queue. (Note: [Read how Finalization works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx)).